# FBE securely wipe all data

Tags: security, factory-reset, data-recovery, encryption

According to [android documentation](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/file-based) the FBE system has two different levels. Credential Encrypted (CE) storage and Device Encrypted (DE) storage.

- Does a factory reset of an FBE phone reset the keys of both storages?
- If I run a full disk encryption on a phone that had FBE enabled by default and then proceed to factory
  reset- will **BOTH** CE and DE keys be different from what they originally
  were before FDE?
- What would hypothetically be recoverable of the previous system assuming full physical access? Data remanence and all. (I assume bootloader is completely unencrypted. Is there anything I'm not aware of like an unencrypted swap or something?)

Comment: A factory reset is designed to erase all keys. A device can only support one encryption method. So you can not use FDE on a device that is FBE.